# Configuration in configmap of fluentd is not getting added in /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, fluentd

I am trying to use fluentd as a daemonSet which will run on a node where my application pods are running and convert the application logs into the stdout, So that it can be used to send to elastic search.

I created a configmap to load/add the extra configuration in `fluent.conf` but when I saw the logs of a daemon set it shows the config file contents where my entries from configmap is not present.

My configmap is like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  fluentd.conf: |
    <source>
      type tail
      format none
      read_from_head true
      path /var/log/node1/app.log
      pos_file /var/log/node1/app.log.pos
      tag noappTag
    </source>
    <match **>
      type stdout
    </match>
```

But still, I am not able to see my contents. Is this normal behavior?

If not, then how can I confirm that fluentd is able to convert my application logs written into file into STDOUT.

> /var/log/node1/app.log

is available inside the fluentd pod. I went inside and checked.

Comment: how do you deploy fluentd? are you mounting configmap into the pod?

Comment: hi @abinet . I am deploying fluentd as a DaemonSet in kube-system namespace and mounting the configmap which is present in same namespace to it. My actual application is running in a different pod under default namespace. It writes logs to directory which is present on host and mounted to fluentd as well on path . So, logs are actually available in fluentd pod under path /var/log/. I verifed this by loggin in to pod using exec

Comment: Please verify this [issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/issues/174) probably you should change fluentd.conf to fluent.conf, [here](https://medium.com/@jkudo/set-configmap-of-fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch-in-kubernetes-de75f9d06285) you can find tutorial. Pleas let me know if this helped

Answer (score 0):

Your have configured this configmap in pod settings ??
If not then please configure configmap setting in pod.yaml file as a volume or env variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which "distribution" of Kubernetes you are running this (AKS, EKS, Minikube, Kind, whatsover...)  but to check if the fluentd is working, you can get "inside" in one of your Clusters Node (with ssh, docker exec /bin/bash, as I said depends on your K8s "distribution") and then take a look at the folder:

```
/var/log/containers
```

You should found some file in there, with the same name of your application's pods (of course if they are deployed at current node). Something like:

```
my-app-1.0-5699665dcb-s8zmz_namespace-a77f8bbf35bd91b105eed52b248bd80b6923.log
```

And also, you should check if a file starting with "fluentd" exists, like this one:

```
fluentd-rzrtl_kube-system_fluentd-a49b6151bee16d4abe5c5f2ea4f1e42bf8.log
```

And then... if you found it, probably the fluentd is working, and then "`tail -f it`", you could found something, like `WARN` or `ERRORS`, regarding parsing the Fluentd.conf (like missing parts of matches, filters, etc.)

Good luck! ;-)